# How much money globally is spent on SEO/SEM a year?

Tags: seo, sem

Wondering how big the market is for SEO/SEM, anyone have any fresh, trustworthy, hard numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's total advertising revenues were USD$23 billion in 2009

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdWords

Answer (score 0):

Too much... :)  in regards to SEO.  95% of seo is in the actual planning and design of a site/application.  The rest is just building backlinks and promoting.

As for SEM, I would est 95% of what google makes per year to be from that. Try researching that figure.